# How can I remove the blue highlight in a tab bar for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've already been able to customize the gray shape that indicates what tab is selected, but how do I change the blue highlight to a different color or remove it completely? I'm building a tab bar with a very specific custom design, and this blue gloss has to go.

Comment: only solution is to create your own custom tabbar

Answer (score 0):

The UITabBar itself, won't allow you to modify it like this. My opinion would be to create your own custom TabBar. Look at this question for further informations: [Really cool way to create custom UITabBar for iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640588/really-cool-way-to-create-custom-uitabbar-for-iphone-app)

Comment: I found the answer myself, in the documentation. http://cl.ly/2P1N2s1A0d2s2c0g2T3t

Comment: Yes, but that's iOS 5-only if you want to provide backward-compatibility you need to create something on your own.